# Replacing a substring from an .txt file and writing to a new .txt file stops after 1 line IN C

Tags: c, string, loops, substring

***First time poster sorry if this is not clear. Im trying to replace a searched word in a txt file with a given word throughout the whole text. It works for the first line but doesn't go further than that. Thanks for any help. my problem part is this and the whole thing is below it:***

```
FILE *input_file = fopen("sentences_test.txt", "r");
char line [LINE_LENGTH];

FILE *write_file = fopen("replaced.txt", "w"); 

while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input_file) != NULL)
    {
    remove_newline(line);
    char *currentWord;
    currentWord = strtok(line, "\n ,.-");


while (currentWord != NULL)
        {
        if (strcmp(search, currentWord)==0 && replace != " ") 
        {
            printf("%s\n", currentWord);


                fprintf (write_file, "%s\n", replace);
        }
else {
      fprintf(write_file, "%s\n", currentWord);

     }
currentWord = strtok(NULL, "\n ,.-");
        }
fclose (write_file);    
fclose(input_file);
```

////WHOLE THING

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#define LINE_LENGTH 5000

void remove_newline(char *str)
{
int len =strlen (str);

if (len>0 &&str[len -1] == '\n')
    str[len -1] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char search[50];
    printf("\n What would you like to search for? ");

    fgets(search,50,stdin);

    int slen = strlen(search);
    printf("%s\n", search);
    remove_newline(search);

    char replace[50];
    printf("Replace word?");
    fgets(replace, 50, stdin);

    FILE *input_file = fopen("sentences_test.txt", "r");
    char line [LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *write_file = fopen("replaced.txt", "w"); 

    while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input_file) != NULL)
        {
        remove_newline(line);
        char *currentWord;
        currentWord = strtok(line, "\n ,.-");


        while (currentWord != NULL)
                {
                if (strcmp(search, currentWord)==0 && replace != " ") 
                {
                    printf("%s\n", currentWord);


                        fprintf (write_file, "%s\n", replace);
                }
        else {
              fprintf(write_file, "%s\n", currentWord);

             }
        currentWord = strtok(NULL, "\n ,.-");
                }
        fclose (write_file);    
        fclose(input_file);



    }
return 0;
}
```

**an eg of output is**
search: the
replaced with: REPLACE!

TEXT FILE: C
is
REPLACE!

most
commonly
used
programming
language
for
writing
operating
systems
The
first
operating
system
written
in
C
is
Unix
Later
operating
systems
like
Linux
were
all
written
in
C
Not
only
is
C
REPLACE!

language
of
operating
systems
it
is
REPLACE!

precursor
and
inspiration
for
almost
all
of
REPLACE!

most
popular
high
level
languages
available
today
In
fact
Perl
PHP
Python
and
Ruby
are
all
written
in
C

THE FILE IS BIGGER THAN THIS

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding the calls to `fgets()`  There are lots of things the user can do to make that fail.  Therefore, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: The function: `fopen()` often fails.  Therefore, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: ` currentWord = strtok(line, "\n ,.-");`  This (probably) will not do what you want.  Strongly suggest using `strstr()` to find an occurrence of the `search` word

Comment: regarding the expression: `&& replace != " ")`  This is trying to compare a char string with a pointer.  This will not work.  Suggest using `strcmp()` to make the comparison

Comment: regarding; `int main(int argc, char **argv)`  This will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  To correct this, suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`:  `int main( void )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
    fclose (write_file);    
    fclose(input_file);
}  <<-- end of `while reading lines of input file
return 0;
```

When the 'read each line' loop completes one iteration, the files are closed, so the next call to `fgets()` fails and the loop exits.

This is why only the first line is processed.

Suggest moving the calls to `fclose()` to AFTER the end of the 'read each line' `while()` loop